# JavaScript setInterval inside bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an infinite periodic get loop:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $('a#log').bind('click', setInterval(function() {
            $.get(
                $LOG + '/json_test',
                {},
                function(data) {
                    document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML = data.replace('\n', '<br/>');
                }
            );
         }, 2000));
  });
</script>
```

If I do this

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $('a#log').bind('click', function() {
            $.get(
                $LOG + '/json_test',
                {},
                function(data) {
                    document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML = data.replace('\n', '<br/>');
                }
            );
         });
  });
</script>
```

All works well, but without infinite loop.

Comment: Please be more specific than "this code doesn't work".

Comment: Just wrap your `setInterval()` in anonymous function.

Comment: I am waiting to have an infinite get loop, from file, every 2 seconds.

Comment: any error in your console

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: setInterval() returns a Number. You are binding that number as your click handler.

Comment: and the right answer goes to @Sacho ...

Answer (score 1):

As @sacho say, `setInterval()` returns a Number. You are binding that number as your click handler instead a function. That's why is not working, but...

You can do something like this is just want to call the ajax function every time is finished, you can't be sure that your response will be every 2000ms.

```
$('a#log').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    infiniteLoop();
})


function infiniteLoop() {
    $.get(
        $LOG + '/json_test',
        {},
        function(data) {
            $("#logs").html(data.replace('\n', '<br/>'));
            infiniteLoop();
        }
    );
}
```

Note: Use jQuery (specially to manage the DOM) every time you can if you already loaded the library

Answer (score 1):

You need wrap your **setInterval** function in a **intermediate function** to prevent it from executed before your click. In other word, a function inside a function.

```
$(function () {
    $('a#log').bind('click', function () {
        setInterval(function () {

            $.get('example.json',{}, function (data) {

                $('#logs').html(JSON.stringify(data).replace('\n', '</br>'));
            });

        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

JSfiddle Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x13sruaf/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a#log').on('click', infiniteLoop);
function infiniteLoop() {
    setInterval(function() {

    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        var refreshIntervalId;
        $('a#log').bind('click', function (){
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
                $.get(
                    $LOG + '/json_test',
                    {},
                    function(data) {
                        document.getElementById("logs").innerHTML = data.replace('\n', '<br/>');
                    }
                );
             }, 2000);
       });
    });
</script>
```